# Find a linear map $T : \mathbb{M}_{1 \times 4}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$ with given Kernel

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a linear map $T : \mathbb{M}_{1 \times 4}(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$ with Kernel generated by
>
> $$ \vec{v_1} = ~[1 ~~2~~3~~4];~~ \vec{v_2} =~[0~~1~~1~~1] $$

Thoughts on this problem:

dim$(\mathbb{M}_{1 \times 4}(\mathbb{R})) = 4$ and dim$(\mathbb{R}^5) = 5$, obviously. So whatever map T I come up with, I know it can be represented by a $5 \times 4$ matrix.

Also, dim(Ker $T$) = $2$, so the above mentioned matrix has two columns which are null. So, $T$ would look something like this.

$$ T= \begin{bmatrix}
 a& e &  0& 0\\ 
 b&  f&  0& 0\\ 
 c&  g&  0& 0\\ 
 d&  h&  0& 0\\ 
 e&  i&  0&0 
\end{bmatrix} $$

What I don't know how to do is choose the values of $a$, $b$, ..., such that $T$ will satisfy the Kernel conditions, which obviously are

$$ T([1~~2~~3~~4]) = ~(0,0,0,0,0)  $$

$$ T([0~~1~~1~~1]) = ~(0,0,0,0,0)  $$

Other ways to tackle this problem are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a good idea to define your transformation on a basis. You want to define it on the two linearly vectors $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, so extend them to a basis of $M_{1 \times 4}(\Bbb{R})$. There are many ways you can do this, for example
$$(v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4) = (\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}).$$
Define $Tv_1 = Tv_2 = 0$, and define $Tv_3$ and $Tv_4$ to be *almost* anything you like. In order to keep the kernel of dimension $2$, we'll need to ensure the rank of this linear map is $2$ (in order to satisfy the rank-nullity theorem). Basically, just choose $Tv_3$ and $Tv_4$ so that they're not multiples of each other, e.g.
\begin{align*}
Tv_3 &= (1, 0, 0, 0, 0) \\
Tv_4 &= (0, 1, 0, 0, 0).
\end{align*}
This defines your $T$ completely!

Comment: This is equivalent to putting your $Tv_3$ and $Tv_4$ as the first and second columns of my $T$. I had thought about that, but thought something was wrong because then I get a matrix with $3$ null row vectors. Wouldn't that make dim(ker $T$) = $3$?

Comment: No, the dimension of the kernel is determined by the number of columns without pivots, which is $2$ (well, at most $2$, depending on the first two columns). The number of zero rows is the codimension of the range, i.e. the number of dimensions fewer in the range than $5 = \operatorname{dim} \Bbb{R}^5$.